# Why is the namelen-parameter in getpeername using a pointer in Winsock?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

This is a question just for interest: why does the `getpeername`-[function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) out of `Winsock` receives the `namelen`-parameter as pointer? In my opinion, this is a major design flaw.

Example:

```
sockaddr_in addr;
int addrLength = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

if (getpeername(s, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&addr), &addrLength /* <- this */) != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, as the documentation you link to describes, it's used for both input and output. On input, it's the size of the buffer you're providing; on output it's the actual size of the structure.

> In my opinion, this is a major design flaw.

It's a minor inconvenience if you know the socket type (and hence address info size) in advance, and can be useful if you don't.

Comment: Thanks, I've overlooked that!

Answer (score 1):

Because

> On return, the namelen parameter contains the actual size, in bytes, of the name parameter returned.

I.e. as the link says, `namelen` is an `_Inout_` parameter, which means you pass information to the function, as well as can expect it to return information in that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a design flaw.  On the contrary, not having the length parameter would be a design flaw.

It is a common pattern to have the client of some subroutine library pass in what the size of a structure was defined as *when the calling program was compiled*.

This way, when a new version of the library (in this case ws2_32.dll) with a different definition of the sockaddr structure is installed, it can be compatible with older programs instead of just crashing.

Without this is parameter, every application using the Winsock library would have to statically link it's own private copy of the Winsock library.  Once such a program was linked and distributed, it would never get the benefit of any library updates.